# How show only the last content or part from my scrollview programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, ios7, uiscrollviewdelegate

well I have a label that show the last string concatenated insert the textfield, but I need to show the last part of the String of the label, I did try to show with scrollview but only shows the first part I want to show that whenever edit the string automatically display the last part is possible?, actually only show the first part and when you scroll, finally show all string from Label like this:

[image]

when I write in textfield the scrollview not show the last part

[image]

when I use the scroll, I can see all the label String.....

[image]

BUT I NEED THIS!!, how show the last part from scrollview programmatically?

the code Im using now is:

```
-(UILabel*)resizeToStretch:(UILabel *)Label{
    float width = [self expectedWidth:Label];
    CGRect newFrame = [Label frame];
    newFrame.size.width = width;
    [Label setFrame:newFrame];
    return Label;
}

-(float)expectedWidth:(UILabel *)Label{
    [Label setNumberOfLines:1];

    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(9999,Label.frame.size.height);

    CGRect expected = [Label.text boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: Label.font} context:nil];

    CGSize expectedLabelSize = expected.size;


    return expectedLabelSize.width;
}

-(IBAction)action:(id)sender
{
    LabelTitulo.text = textfieldTexto.text;
    LabelTitulo = [self resizeToStretch:LabelTitulo];
    NSLog(@"%@",LabelTitulo.text);

    scroll.contentSize = LabelTitulo.frame.size;  
    [scroll addSubview:LabelTitulo];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldReturn:");
           [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self action:textfieldTexto];
    return YES;
}

//------------------------------------------//
//           THANKS StackOverFlow           //
//          GRETTINGS FROM BOLIVIA          //
//             ROCK ON!!!! n_n'             //
//------------------------------------------//
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
CGPoint widthOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.contentSize.width - self.scrollView.bounds.size.width);
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:widthOffset animated:YES];
```

to get the scroll view to the bottom/left.

You might also try to align right your label view.